# Citations not showing up in text and bibliography for authoryear style

Tags: bibliographies, natbib

I have the codes below.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{hyperref}      

\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{colortbl,hhline}
\usepackage[x11names]{xcolor}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{appendix}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage[flushleft]{threeparttable}
\usepackage{amsmath}

% Natbib setup for author-year style
\usepackage[authoryear]{natbib}
 \bibpunct[, ]{(}{)}{,}{a}{}{,}%
 \def\bibfont{\small}%
 \def\bibsep{\smallskipamount}%
 \def\bibhang{24pt}%
 \def\newblock{\ }%
 \def\BIBand{and}%

\begin{document}
blablabla

\clearpage
\bibliographystyle{authoryear} 
\bibliography{references}

\end{document}
```

But this does not work. Citations show `?` in the article, and do not show up in the bibliography.
If I change sytle to `\bibliographystyle{plain}` , it works and shows number 1, 2, 3, etc. in the article. But I want to have author year style.

Here is an example of one citation in the `references.bib`.

```
@article{Adjerid2022,
  title={Gain-loss incentives and physical activity: the role of choice and wearable health tools},
  author={Adjerid, I. and Loewenstein, G. and Purta, R. and Striegel, A.},
  journal={Management Science},
  volume={68},
  number={4},
  pages={2377-3174},
  year={2022},
  publisher={INFORMS}
}
```

Is there anything wrong with my code?

Comment: I don't know an authoryear style. Do you get warnings from bibtex?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer no warnings. Author style will give citations in the article like this, Adjerid (2022) shows ....

Comment: Show the blg file and your log file.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Oh, it actually shows "I couldn't open style file authoryear.bst : \bibstyle{authoryear : }"